# How to plot $f(x)=x^{2/3}$

Tags: calculus

I'm using Leithold's book to teach calculus. In a exercise Leithold asks how to draw $f(x)=x^{2/3}$. I don't know how to plot this function since I can't use the derivative methods he develop afterwards. Until this page of the book Leithold only covers limits, continuity, tangents and basic derivatives. He didn't talk about concavity, inflection points, absolute values, etc. yet.

So How do I plot this function using only the definitions he made until this exercise?

Comment: got to Wolfram Alpha

Comment: I would suggest to make a table of values. (How many students can actually do that?) Particular $x$ values of interest are the ones of which the cube root can be taken (including negative values). The derivative at zero might be an point worth discussing in class.

Comment: Always check if the function is even or odd, in this case it's even, so half of your job's done, and you can plot it in the first quadrant by taking points or by noting that it's nature will be of the form of $y=x^{\frac{1}{n}}$ where n is an integer

Answer (score 0):

Using continuity, you can find that f is continuous at the origin:

$$
\lim_{x \to 0} f(x) = f(0) = 0 \\
$$

Using limits, you can find what happens at the ends:

$$
\lim_{x \to -\infty} f(x) = +\infty \\
\lim_{x \to +\infty} f(x) = + \infty \\
$$

Using limits, you can find the inclination of the tagent line at the origin:

$$
\begin{eqnarray}
f'(0) &=& \lim_{\Delta x \to 0} \frac{f(0 + \Delta x) - f(0)}{\Delta x} \\
&=& \lim_{\Delta x \to 0} \frac{(\Delta x)^{2/3} - 0}{\Delta x} \\
&=& \lim_{\Delta x \to 0} \frac{1}{(\Delta x)^{1/3}} \\
&=& \infty
\end{eqnarray}
$$

Using more limits, you can find the inclination of the tangent line at any point:

$$
\begin{eqnarray}
f'(x) &=& \lim_{\Delta x \to 0} \frac{f(x + \Delta x) - f(x)}{\Delta x} \\
&=& \lim_{\Delta x \to 0} \frac{(x + \Delta x)^{2/3} - x^{2/3}}{\Delta x} \\
&=& \lim_{\Delta x \to 0} \frac{[(x + \Delta x)^{2/3} - x^{2/3}][(x + \Delta x)^{4/3} + (x + \Delta x)^{2/3}x^{2/3} + x^{4/3}]}{\Delta x[(x + \Delta x)^{4/3} + (x + \Delta x)^{2/3}x^{2/3} + x^{4/3}]} \\
... \\
&=& \lim_{\Delta x \to 0} \frac{2x + \Delta x}{(x + \Delta x)^{4/3} + (x + \Delta x)^{2/3}x^{2/3} + x^{4/3}} \\
&=& \frac{2x}{x^{4/3} + x^{2/3}x^{2/3} + x^{4/3}} \\
&=& \frac{2}{3x^{1/3}}
\end{eqnarray}
$$

You now know the graph tends to $+\infty$ at the ends, that it is continuous at the origin but the tangent line has an inclination of $\pi/2$, and that the inclination is negative when $x < 0$ and positive when $x > 0$. That should be plenty to draw a nice graph.

Answer (score 0):

Evaluate the function for perfect cubes, giving you perfect squares.

$$(0,0),(\pm1,1),(\pm8,4),(\pm27,9),(\pm64,16).$$

This is more than enough to draw a curve and guess how it behaves.